# Windows kernel32.dll only assembly draw pixel

Tags: windows, assembly, x86-64, kernel32

I've been looking on stack overflow but couldn't seem to find anything

What commands and functions specifically from kernel32.dll on windows 64 bit can draw a single pixel on the screen, preferably with no user32.dll windows?

Comment: [`DeviceIoControl`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/ioapiset/nf-ioapiset-deviceiocontrol?redirectedfrom=MSDN). It allows an application to send messages to a driver. Note that since Vista, Windows is using [DWM and it's client library DirectComposition](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directcomp/architecture-and-components) (but if you have a WinRT compatible compiler, [the visual layer is easier](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/using-the-visual-layer-with-win32)). DirectComposition talk to the kernel with *undocumented* ...

Comment: ... IORPs (pretty much like GDI does) and the win32k.sys driver passes the commands to the userspace DWM process. I don't know if the video driver lets you write to the framebuffer but anyway that's still IORPs. I don't think any syscall is dedicated to the graphics (besides the generic one for the IORPs). Surely kernel32.dll has no graphic API.

Comment: @margaret ok thanks, so there's no documented way of taking to the monitor driver, meaning on the next windows update it could break?

Comment: Actually, I was **wrong**. I though win32k didn't create additional syscalls, instead, it does (it makes sense). After a quick reverse engineering of user32.dll, I found some syscall numbers and was able to [find a bit of documentation](https://reactos.org/wiki/Techwiki:Win32k/syscalls). Not sure if I can use that to draw a pixel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turned out I was **wrong** in my [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63398081/windows-kernel32-dll-only-assembly-draw-pixel?noredirect=1#comment112108471_63398081).

[win32k.sys does create new syscalls](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/DynamoRIO/drmemory/+/refs/heads/master/drsyscall/drsyscall_numx.h). Retroactively speaking, it makes sense.

*win32k.sys* handles the [DirectComposition engine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directcomp/architecture-and-components), it's kind of the Desktop and Windows manager of Windows:

[image: DirectComposition architecture]

The DirectComposition API is exposed to Win32 programs through COM which makes it quite difficult to work with without Visual Studio because we'd need the full IDL definition and, in assembly, make the offsets in the vtables manually.
It is also quite abstract, so it'd be a pain to reverse-engineering the syscalls used and then use them.

However, GDI, the legacy Windows' graphic API, is still supported, of course (it's emulated by/integrated with DirectComposition).
This API is exposed through the exported functions of a few DLLs and rather than working in terms of composable surfaces it works in terms of Windows and Device Contexts (objects that allows one to draw).
This makes it easy to reverse-engineering it and use it in assembly.

The closest thing to draw a pixel on screen is drawing a pixel on the desktop device context (since the desktop is a fullscreen window).
With the Win32 API we'd do that with two functions:

- `GetDC`, when called with a NULL value gives the device context of the desktop.
- `SetPixel`, draw a pixel on a device context.

Without the Win32 API but only with direct system calls it could be problematic because it's not a granted that these operations exist on the lower-level interface.
For example, this interface could expose a shared memory area where to write the pixel, with an undocumented format.
Analogously, the device context could be a Win32 abstraction.

But luckily this is *not the case*, both `GetDC` and `SetPixel` have their own syscall.
This is being very lucky and probably derives from the history of win32k.sys (which was much more coupled with the Win32 API, actually being the Win32 API, IIRC).

I reverse-engineered those two Win32 API to get the syscall numbers and how they are used (both numbers are found in the second link in this answer).
While `GetDC` is just a wrapper for the syscall call, `SetPixel` does some format conversion of the color.
In the example given below, this conversion is omitted and if needed is up to you (you may not be able to write the colors you want without it).

I've made an example program that draws a black 256x256 rectangle in the upper left corner of the screen.

[image: Black rectangle]

Some notes:

- It's a 64-bit program, so it can use the `syscall` instruction. This is just for the show (and to avoid explaining what the `WOW32Reserved` pointer and WOW64 are and how to use them).
- If the program can't get the desktop handle it will trigger a debug exception.
- At the top, there are the constants used for the syscall numbers, they are set for Windows 7 (not sure which exact minor version if there is any at all).
- The program was assembled with *NASM* and linked with *golink*.
- It's quite a boring program. Avoiding the Win32 API doesn't add any insight to the programming. If I were you, I'd use the API.

There are no external PE dependencies:

[image: No dependencies]

```
DEFAULT REL

GLOBAL main

%define SYS_GetDC                 100ah
%define SYS_SetPixel              10afh


SECTION .text

;.    .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .
; . -   . -   . -   . -   . -   . -   . -   . -   . -   . -   . -   . -   . -
;
;Get the HDC of a window
;
;.    .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .
; . -   . -   . -   . -   . -   . -   . -   . -   . -   . -   . -   . -   . -

;arg0 (rcx) = HWND
GetDC:
  mov r10, rcx
  mov eax, SYS_GetDC
  syscall
  ret

;.    .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .
; . -   . -   . -   . -   . -   . -   . -   . -   . -   . -   . -   . -   . -
;
;Set a pixel in an HDC
;
;.    .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .
; . -   . -   . -   . -   . -   . -   . -   . -   . -   . -   . -   . -   . -

SetPixel:
  mov r10, rcx
  mov eax, SYS_SetPixel
  syscall
  ret

;.    .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .
; . -   . -   . -   . -   . -   . -   . -   . -   . -   . -   . -   . -   . -
;
;Main
;
;.    .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .
; . -   . -   . -   . -   . -   . -   . -   . -   . -   . -   . -   . -   . -

main:

  ;Get the desktop HDC

  xor ecx, ecx
  call GetDC
  test eax, eax
  jz .abort

  ;Write a 256x256 black square
  mov ebx, eax          ;HDC into rbx (which is preserved)
  
  xor esi, esi          ;esi = x = 0    
  
.x_loop:  
  xor edi, edi          ;edi = y = 0
  
.y_loop: 
  mov ecx, ebx      ;HDC
  mov edx, edi      ;Y
  mov r8, rsi       ;X
  xor r9, r9        ;Color (black, beware of the correct format!)
  call SetPixel

  inc edi           ;y++
  cmp edi, 100h
  jb .y_loop        ;while (y < 256)
 
  inc esi           ;x++
  cmp esi,  100h    
  jb .x_loop        ;while (x < 256)


  ;In Windows we can return from main
  ret




  ;Here something went wrong
  ;We must do some eye-catching action, like invoking the debugger

.abort:
  ;This will trigger a debug popup
  int3
```

Comment: Note that these syscall numbers are likely to change with Windows updates, so this is for fun only.

Comment: @CodyGray It's not even that fun :) Just for curiosity. I've remarked that this is for Win7 only and there's *absolutely* no point in this.

Comment: DirectComposition is a Windows 8  thing. This is probably the closest answer to DWM internals on SO. I've been meaning to look into this myself. It's probably the hardest and most obscure area of NT OS that has almost zero information online so you'd have to remote debug using windbg etc, Ida pro, sysinternals. As a guess on win7 I'd say win32k.sys informs DWM.exe of new windows probably using ALPC. CDD creates GDI surface and probably tells dxgkrnl to create the directx texture in VRAM. It's obviously inserted into the window data structure in some way and dwm uses directx dll to composite it